# std::initializer_list that can be sorted

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to `std::sort` an `std::initializer_list`;

```
  real_t median(const std::initializer_list<real_t> vars) {
    const unsigned x = vars.size() / 2;
    // std::sort(vars.begin(), vars.end());
    if (x & 1) {
      return *(vars.begin() + x);
    }
    return (*(vars.begin() + x) + *(vars.begin() + x + 1)) * 0.5;
  }
```

This gives an obscure error which I predict is because the internal elements of the list are of `const &`, thus they can't be sorted.

What alternatives do I have for a mutable list on the **stack** that will compile with `-pedantic` ?

I'm using C++11. Templates are not optimal unless they can be forward instantiated for all combinations of parameters, or have a small range I can `extern`.

Comment: Do you realise you have declared the paramater as const?
initialze lists are often pass-by-value, as is yours, and thus rarely need to be const.

Comment: Hi, I used `const` because it made it more obvious there were `const` internal elements. Removing `const` doesn't allow it to compile. I have another function like this one, but it's pass by ref so a solution that works for both would be welcome. :)

Comment: There might be some insane solution with variadic templates where you can get the compiler to sort the list at compile time.  Any reason you  cant put the list in a seperate include file and sort it before the compiler sees it?

Comment: I have a solution here: https://gist.github.com/kvanberendonck/7783060 , but it doesn't work with some of the non-basic types I need to use, say, a struct.

Comment: hmm, you might want to add the c++11 tag, you will get the specailists in that way

Comment: minor note, `(x & 1)` is wrong test for oddness, since x is half size, not size, while median cares about the oddness of the size.

Comment: I have an answer, will post up soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)(both `const` and not) cannot be [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)ed. That's because its iterators are read-only (its iterator type is `const T*`, a pointer to a `const` `T`).

For your function to work, you must use a container that satisfies the requirements of `std::sort`. Probably the best container for that would be [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

```
real_t median(std::vector<real_t> vars) {  // Without the const
```

If you want a stack-based (fixed-sized) container, then you could use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), which is also `std::sort`able.

Comment: This puts an allocation on the heap. It's going to be expensive just for passing some information across. Thanks though.

Comment: array requires knowing size at compile time doesnt it? 
And this problem is kind of trivial if vector was an acceptable solution.

Comment: But, if the data is read-only where it is, and thus you NEED to copy it to somewhere else, I am not sure copying it to the heap vs the stack will make that much difference in terms of speed.

Comment: @RichardPlunkett Yes. For your `median` function to work with `std::array`s of different sizes, you could make it a template, though it may not be optimal in your case.

Comment: The overhead is the ~150ns allocation time and further deallocation time which is almost as much time as what's going to be actually spent in the function.

Comment: I'm rewriting a piece of software, and the previous version uses the vector technique everywhere. Finding something that I can use instead of all the vectors is a pretty significant optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working:

```
  template <size_t N>
  real_t median_helper(std::array<real_t, N> & vars) {
    std::sort(vars.begin(), vars.end());
    const unsigned n = vars.size() >> 1;
    if (vars.size() & 1) {
      return vars[n];
    }
    return (vars[n] + vars[n + 1]) * 0.5;
  }

  template <typename...T>
  real_t median(T const & ... args) {
    std::array<real_t, sizeof...(args)> vars = {args...};
    return median_helper(vars);
  }
```

Uses `std::array` and it's on the stack. Unfortunately, it's a template solution.

Comment: nb: If you use a struct instead of `real_t` the braces on line 13 need to be double or you won't pass -Wall, like this: `{{args...}}`.

Comment: FYI `::std::vector` can also allocate from the stack with the help of a stack allocator.

Comment: +1 useful to know, but no std:: implementations yet.

Comment: use: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31528/a-working-stack-allocator or write your own if you prefer.